# Prime factor in c++ code does not work for all inputs

Tags: c++, prime-factoring

This code, I supposed, would give me the largest prime factor for composite number input. However, it works for some inputs and doesn't for others.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int num=1, sum, count=0, test;
cin>>test;
while(num<=(sqrt(test)))
{
    if(test%num==0)
    {
        for (int prime=2; num>prime; prime++)
        {
            if(num%prime==0)
            count ++;
        }
        if (count == 0)
            sum=num;
    }
    num++;
}
cout<<sum;
}
```

Examples for where it does not work:

input: 6, expected: 3, got: 2;

input: 540, expected: 5, got: 3;

input: 600, expected: 5, got: 3;

Can somebody tell me what to change?

Comment: Please give an example where it does not work. i.e. the input and what is expected

Comment: Also move the `sqrt` out of the while condition for speed

Comment: You limit your search to numbers no larger than `sqrt(test)`. This means that, at least for numbers that are a product of two primes, you can only find the smaller of the two. In this case, the smaller prime is necessarily `<= sqrt(test)`, and the larger one is `>= sqrt(test)`

Comment: Of course it doesn't work because `3>sqrt(6)`.

Comment: Thn u all for pointing all of that out

Comment: Does not work for numbers that exceed about 150,000,000. But I need it to work for 1,000,000,000,000. Can u tell me something I can do to the code for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the largest prime factor, you need to check all the way to `test/2`.  E.g. For 38, you'll currently only check up to 6, and miss 19.

Also, you need to rest count after each test.

Answer (score 2):

You must add

`count = 0`

after

`if (count == 0)
   sum = num;`

Also when input number is prime then largest prime divisor is input number itself. In this case  variable `sum` never inited. Init it in begin of programm to `0` and after `while` loop add

`if (sum == 0)
   sum = test;`

Comment: I thought for it to work for composite only coz thats easy

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but still:

```
  int main() {
  auto num = 1;
  auto sum = 0;
  auto count = 0;
  auto test = 0;

  std::cin >> test;

  while (num <= test / 2) {
    count = 0;
    if (test % num == 0) {
      for (auto prime = 2; num > prime; prime++) {
        if (num % prime == 0) count++;
      }
      if (count == 0) sum = num;
    }
    num++;
  }
  std::cout << sum;
}
```

You can use auto. Also as a general tip: don't use "using namespace std". Getting used to writing std:: will save you some trouble, when working in bigger projects.